# How to run a series of checks governed by a mysql table and store the results

Tags: mysql

I have to run a series of checks (governed by the table "Checks") and store the results in a table "Checks_result" (in a mysql database).

The table "Checks" contains an identifier (checkno) and a sql-statement (possibly returning many rows with a single value) to be executed.

The table "Check_results" has to contain all the rows returned from the sql-statement, with a reference to checkno and an autoincrement row checkentry for each returned row from the sql-statement.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can use INSERT ... SELECT type statements, these could just append the SELECT from the Checks table to a standard INSERT bit and run the query.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Nigel, maybe I wasn't exactly clear in the formulation of the problem, but how do I get (dynamically ie not in the sql-statement) the checkno column to the returned results and a run over over all the records from the check table?

Comment: Can you add an example to your question, it would make it a lot easier

Comment: Sure, see this image: <img src=http://www.raphoto.nl/dbschema.png />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was suggesting was when your table has the 2 SQL statements, you should read each record and construct another SQL statement along the lines of:

```
insert into check_results(checkno, checkresult )
select 1, i.val1-i.val2 from import i;
```

The select just needs the checkno added into it and the checkentry should be an autoincrement column.

Comment: Thanks, that was the bit I needed.